# Using searborn.barplot to plot a pandas dataframe when there are multiple factors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

[image]

There are 10 different types of "roi"s, and 8 different types of "emb".

I want to make 10 sns bar plot. Each plot is for one roi.

Then in each plot, the x-axis grids are "emb"s (i.e., w2v, bert, ...). The y-axis is the acc, that is averaged across "sbj" (subjects, there are 3 subjects in total).

When I check the sns.barplot tutorial page, I thought I might use like this:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="emb", y="acc", data=df_im)
```

But it does not make seperations across roi's.

Results:
[image]

How should I modify the code to make calculations only for one particular "roi"?

Comment: I usually just filter the df in these situations.  use df_im['roi'].unique() to get the unique list of values in the 'roi' column. Then iterate over the list, filter with df_filtered=df[df['roi']== element_of_list] and create your plot for that specific roi value with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just the ***PPA*** **roi** try:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="emb", y="acc", data=df_im[df_im.roi == "PPA"])
```